# AtmosphereFramework in clustered environmet

Tags: java, cloud, cluster-computing, hazelcast, atmosphere

Is it possible to replace the default AtmosphereResourceFactory and AtmosphereResourceSession in order to be able to replicate atmosphereresources and sessions in the cloud and if yes how?

I'm using latest Atmosphere 2.2.4 and I'm also using Hazelcast support

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible. AtmospherePro is exactly doing that (using Hazelcast as well). All you need to do it to write your own AtmosphreObjectfactory and inject your own implementation of the class above.

http://async-io.org/AtmospherePro.html

-- Jeanfrancois